# R - How to Return All Rows Below Selected Specific Rows in a Dataframe?

Tags: r, database, dataframe

So I have this this data frame with these values

```
page_name         activity
Home              View Page
New Project       View Page
New Project       Submit Form
New Project       View Page
Expenses          View Page
Quotes            View Page
New Project       View Page
New Project       Submit Form
New Project       View Page
Payment Claims    View Page
```

I'm trying to get all the pages that are two rows below the rows whose page name is 'New Project' and activity is 'Submit Form' in a new dataframe like this.

```
page_name         activity
Expenses          View Page
Payment Claims    View Page
```

I used this R code to get all the rows who follows the conditions I need.

```
after_newproj <- with(dat, dat[((page_name == 'New Project' & activity == 'Submit Form')),] )
```

Now I tried using this to get what I want to happen and it returns the same number of rows but all null.

```
after_newproj <- with(dat, dat[((page_name == 'New Project' & activity == 'Submit Form')),] + c(2) )
```

Comment: Using base R, something like `idx <- which(df$page_name == "NewProject" & df$activity == "SubmitForm") + 2L; df[idx[idx <= nrow(df)],]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("page_name,activity
Home,View Page
New Project,View Page
New Project,Submit Form
New Project,View Page
Expenses,View Page
Quotes,View Page
New Project,View Page
New Project,Submit Form
New Project,View Page
Payment Claims,View Page", sep=",", header=T)
```

#### dplyr solution

`lead-lag` functions of `dplyr` are helpful in these cases

```
library(dplyr)
df[lag(df$page_name,2)=="New Project" & lag(df$activity,2)=="Submit Form",]
```

#### Output

```
         page_name  activity
1:        Expenses View Page
2:  Payment Claims View Page
```

Comment: This is a little confusing imo since your're loading data.table just for `fread` (not necessary imo) and you're loading dplyr for lead/lag but then not making use of dplyr syntax. Btw, data.table also has such functionality (`shift`).

Comment: Are there better ways of reading in OP's data without `fread`? (It's the best way I could think of...) I didn't think `dplyr` syntax was necessary in this case. (I don't have anything against dplyr syntax...) Nothing against data.table verbs (I just don't really use data.table much...)

Comment: The dplyr solution solved my problem, thank you a lot! I'll be considering to study more of this library.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is that you create additional fields which can then be filtered 
 Code updated....it now works.

## function to help with filtering

```html
global.counter <- 2

fill.filler <- function(x){
if(x == "Break") 
        global.counter <<- 0 
else 
        global.counter <<- global.counter + 1
        return(global.counter)
}
```

## code to filter out the rows needed

```html
df %>%
  mutate(fill = if_else(page_name == "New Project" & activity == "Submit Form", "Break", "Count")) %>%
  mutate(counter = sapply(.$fill, fill.filler)) %>%
  filter(counter <= 2,
         activity != "Submit Form") %>% 
  select(-c(fill, counter))
```

It's important the global.counter be set at 2 otherwise the first few rows will also be included in the final selection which you want to avoid.

Hope the code is easy enough to understand.

Comment: There is no need to use code snippets when answering R questions. Please also double check your results; they don't seem to match OP's desired output